# Rails multiple records select and apply multiple actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am quite new at rails and I am having some trouble designing an admin dashboard.

What I want to achieve is this:

Have a list of multiple users from database.

Have the ability to select multiple records.

Have the ability to apply different actions to all of the 
selected records.

The actions MAY not be directly translatable into SQL queries. (for example send an email)

I am not looking for a complete solution to the problem just a general description on how to approach this. I have a feeling I started on a wrong path.

So far I am doing this:

view

```
<%= form_tag("some_path", method: "get") do %>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", users.id %>
    <%end%>
<%= submit_tag("Send Email") %>
<%end%>
```

controller

```
def send_email
    @recipients = User.find(params[:user_ids])
    @recipients.each do |recipient|
        Notifier.raw_email(recipient.email, params[:user_email][:subject], params[:user_email][:body]).deliver
    end
end
```

This works as it is but i can only apply one action, send email that is.
I want to be able to choose an action to apply to all selected records or apply multiple actions to the selected records

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you could redirect back to the list preserving the selection so new actions can be performed on that selection, another option is using the activeadmin gem which has bash actions in it. http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-batch-actions.html

Comment: You can also list number of action on the same page, may be checkboxes "send mail", "Send Invite", "Request Details", send the number of actions selected with the number of users selected. In controller define another method "def handle_actions", use `case` for actions, then for each action call methods, e.g. send_email(number_of_users), request_details(number_of_users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `send` method to call methods of the model.

```
class User
  def send_email(subject, body)
    Notifier.raw_email(self.email, subject, body).deliver
  end      
end
```

Let `/some_path` also accept an array of `actions`

In our case `actions = ['send_email']`

In the action that `some_path` resolves to,

```
class SomeController < ActionController::Base
  def some_action # that some_path resolves to in your config/routes.rb
    @recipients = User.find(params[:user_ids])
    @actions = params[:actions]
    @recipients.each do |recipient|
      @actions.each do |action|
        recipient.send(action, params[:subject], params[:body])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In this way you can call multiple methods. Make sure you only accept valid `action` values or else the admin can simply call any of the User's methods.

Comment: this seems like an amazing solution. Could you please give me an example on how that some_path route should look like? Right now I am using this: /user_email/new which sends me to the email composer page transporting all the ids forward untill it reaches the send_email action

Comment: add " get :some_path, controller: :some_controller, action: :some_action " in your config/routes.rb. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: sorry for asking stupid questions.. What I am confused about is how to pass those action parameters in my view file

Comment: similar to the checkboxes you've added for all the user records, perhaps you can have a set of 'action' checkboxes for the entire page?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a select tag with the different actions you need.

Then on change of the select tag, you can update the action attribute of the form. eg, using jQuery.

```
$('#my-action-select').change(function() {
  $('#myform').attr('action', $(this).val)
})
```

Comment: I feel like this would only make it choose an action not send multiple actions but it's a great shout though +1